# drupal templates displaying incomplete html tags

Tags: php, drupal

I have been asked to take a look at a drupal site that i did not build due to an interesting error.  I have done all possible maint on the site that i can find however the issues is that in displaying lists of articles the tags are getting all messed up to be such as :
12/31/1969 580 " style="color: #054c7f;"> Trade Up For Summer BBQ Season!
in the direct display of a browser,  The source leads to a broken view system or something im not quite sure on but i have spent a few hours to run cache clear and check permissions and nothing is strange there. An example of some source just for a title of an article :

```
    <div>
    <h2>12/31/1969 <a href="/News/Detail/?id=&lt;span id=" thmr_273"="" class="thmr_call">
  580

" style="color: #054c7f;"&gt;<span id="thmr_257" class="thmr_call">
  <span id="thmr_258" class="thmr_call">
  Trade Up For Summer BBQ Season!</span>

</span>

</a></h2>
    <p><span id="thmr_261" class="thmr_call">
  <span id="thmr_262" class="thmr_call">
  Unique scoring system to guide grillers to a perfect barbeque</span>

</span>

</p>
    <a href="/News/Detail/?id=&lt;span id=" thmr_273"="" class="thmr_call">
  580

"&gt;&gt; Read More</a>
</div>
```

It seems like a template broke somewhere i just cannot seem to find it, i know the url is domain/news, is there an easy way to find it by the uri?  I have templates named newsroom an archives, i am assuming newsroom.  By the way this whole site was working just a week ago, that is the main reason I am confused as to why it is not working currently.

UPDATE: After doing lots of research i found it was the ThemeDeveloper module that was causing an issue, Anyone that experinces this unless your actually developing a theme DISABLE THIS MODULE It causes errors in the php calls causing incomplete tags on any entry of an article.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Drupal 7 look through the "[template suggestion](https://drupal.org/node/1089656)" rules to see which templates are being called.

Comment: Actually this is a site on drupal 6 sorry forgot to mention that